# Rails: ActionMailer creating faulty links https//link.com instead of https://link.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a actionmailer with settings:

config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => "cool@gmail.com",
  :password             => "cool",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "https://pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/"
```

which delivers an email when a user is created. however, I checked the email that was sent and the links don't work. Here's the template for the email:

```
Dear <%= @user.name %>,

<p>
    Welcome to Pholder! Get started by finding and inviting <%= link_to "friends", users_url %> so that you can exclusively upload and view pictures with each other.
</p>

<p>
    <%= link_to "View profile", user_url(@user) %>
    <%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_url(@user) %>
</p>

<p>
    Sincerely, <br>
    Pholder Staff
</p>
```

and when I checked the actual email:

```
Dear Ellen,

Welcome to Pholder! Get started by finding and inviting friends so that you can exclusively upload and view pictures with each other.

View profile Edit profile

Sincerely,
Pholder Staff
```

None of the links work. The first link that was supposed to send me to `users_url` sends me to: `https//pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/users` instead. This goes for the other 2 links(the `user_url(@user)` sends me to `https//pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/users/9` and etc.)

Is it because I'm setting the default_url incorrectly?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong to what is happening. Where do you expect them to send you?

Comment: there is a colon `:` missing on the urls generated @felipeclopes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the configuration this way:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :protocol => 'https', :host => 'pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com' }
```

Instead of setting the way you are currently doing.

If it don't generate the absolute URL you'll have to set the `:only_path => false`, but it is just a behavior that happens when using the `url_for` as in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html).

Comment: hey felipe, eventually I just did `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com' }` which made it work. i didn't try your way though, but I think I understand it